# C# SSH tunnel Postgres database connection

Tags: c#, ssh, npgsql, ssh-tunnel, ssh.net

I am trying to connect to the Postgres database on remote server through SSH tunnel. I am using SSH.NET and Npgsql library. Here is my example code:

```
using (var client = new SshClient("210.130.90.110", "root", "pasword"))
{
    client.Connect();

    if (!client.IsConnected)
    {
        // Display error
        Console.WriteLine("Client not connected!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
    }

    var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 15432, "210.130.90.110", 5432);
    client.AddForwardedPort(port);

    port.Start();

    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=dbname;Port=15432;User Id=dbuser;Password=dbpassword;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
    }

    port.Stop();
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

After code execution I get:

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException: 'Exception while reading from stream'
>   EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

I am able to connect to database using DBeaver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remote end of the port forwarding is resolved on the server. So you need set the IP address/hostname in a way that works, as it you are connecting *from the server itself*.

The database probably listens on the `localhost` interface only. Not on the public IP address (if it were, you possibly would not need the port forwarding in the first place).

Additionally, it is not a good idea to hard-code the local forwarded port. You cannot know, if that port is not already occupied by another application. Let the system choose any free local port.

```
var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1", 5432);
client.AddForwardedPort(port);
port.Start();

string connString =
    $"Server={port.BoundHost};Database=dbname;Port={port.BoundPort};" +
     "User Id=dbuser;Password=dbpassword;";

using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
}
```

Related: [MySQL port forwading in SSH.NET - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58852459/850848)