# MySQL port forwading in SSH.NET - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh, portforwarding, ssh.net

Installed Plesk on my VS. After this I can't setup SSH-tunnel to get data from other server-database. Using SSH.NET with below code. (This code works locally). Configured to allow communication for port 3306 in Plesk firewall. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Error:

> [SocketException (0x271d): An attempt was made to access a socket in a
>   way forbidden by its access permissions]

Code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string IP = "ssh.xxxxxxxx.xxx";
string Username = "xxxxxxxxxx";
string password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
var connInfo = new Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo(IP, Username, password);
using (var sshClient = new Renci.SshNet.SshClient(connInfo))
{
    sshClient.Connect();

    if (sshClient.IsConnected)
    {
        Renci.SshNet.ForwardedPortLocal port =
            new Renci.SshNet.ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 3306, "xxxxxxxx", 3306);
        sshClient.AddForwardedPort(port);
        port.Start();
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=3306;UID=xxxxxx;PASSWORD=xxxxxxx;DATABASE=xxxxxxx; convert zero datetime=True"))
        {
            string tmpsql = "Select fname,lname,username FROM tbluser Where id=@id";

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(tmpsql, con))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = UserID;
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
    sshClient.Disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local port which you are trying to forward is most probably already used by another application (like a local MySQL database server).

Use another port. Or even better, let the system pick any free local port:

```
var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", "dbserver.example.com", 3306);
client.AddForwardedPort(port);
port.Start();

var connectionString =
    $"SERVER={port.BoundHost};PORT={port.BoundPort};" + 
     "UID=xxxxxx;PASSWORD=xxxxxxx;DATABASE=xxxxxxx; convert zero datetime=True";
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // ...
}
```

Related: [C# SSH tunnel Postgres database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58207371/850848)